# Как укоротить код php и сделать его более читабельным?

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

```
<?php

if (!empty($_COOKIE['sid'])) {
session_id($_COOKIE['sid']);
}

session_start();
require_once 'classes/Auth.class.php';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Penguin - Интернет-магазин стильной бижутерии.</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="#" />
  <meta name="description" content="Penguin - Інтернет-магазин стильний бижетерии" />

  <?php include ('_files/_head.php');?>

 </head>

 <body id="home" data-page="catalog">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="templatemo_wrapper">

  <?php 
   include ('_files/_header.php');
   include ('_files/_ddsmoothmenu.php');
  ?>

  <div class="cleaner h20"></div>
  <div id="templatemo_main_top"></div>
  <div id="templatemo_main">

  <?php include ('_files/_sidebar.php'); ?>

   <div id="content">

    <script id="catalog-template" type="text/template">
     <% _.each(goods, function(good) { %>
     <% }); %>
    </script>

    <?php if (Auth\User::isAuthorized()): ?>

     <h2>Мой кабинет</h2>
      <div class="row" >
       <div style="padding: 0px 30px 0;" class="col-sm-5" >                                  

 <?php
 $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

 $link = mysqli_connect( 
        'localhost',  /* Хост, к которому мы подключаемся */ 
        'root',       /* Имя пользователя */ 
        '',   /* Используемый пароль */ 
        'megalik8');     /* База данных для запросов по умолчанию */ 

 if (!$link) { 
 printf("Невозможно подключиться к базе данных. Код ошибки: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); 
 exit; 
} 

 /* Посылаем запрос серверу */ 
 if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$user_id'")) { 

 /* Выборка результатов запроса */ 
 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){ 
    printf("<h4>Ваш ID: <div style='float:right;'><b class='label-orange label-primary'>%s</b></div></h4>
            <h4>Ваш E-mail: <div style='float:right;'><b class='label-orange label-primary'>%s</b></div></h4>", $row['id'], $row['username']); 
 } 
 /* Освобождаем используемую память */ 
 mysqli_free_result($result); 
}


/* Посылаем запрос серверу */ 
if ($result_orders = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) as count_rows FROM `orders` WHERE client_id='$user_id'") or die(mysql_error())) { 

/* Выборка результатов запроса */ 
while( $row_orders = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_orders) ){ 
    $count_rows = $row_orders['count_rows'];
    echo "<h4>Кол-во заказов: <div style='float:right;'><b class='label-orange label-primary'>".$count_rows." шт.</b></div></h4>";
} 

/* Освобождаем используемую память */ 
mysqli_free_result($result_orders); 
} 

/*Посылаем запрос серверу */ 
if ($result_otckaz = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) as otckaz_rows FROM `orders` WHERE client_id='$user_id' AND status='6'") or die(mysql_error())) { 

/* Выборка результатов запроса */ 
while( $row_otckaz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_otckaz) ){ 
$otckaz_rows = $row_otckaz['otckaz_rows'];
    echo "<h4>Отменено заказов: <div style='float:right;'><b class='label-orange orange'>".$otckaz_rows." шт.</b></div></h4>";
} 

/* Освобождаем используемую память */ 
mysqli_free_result($result_otckaz); 
} 


/*Посылаем запрос серверу */ 
if ($result_count_not = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) as count_not_rows FROM `orders` WHERE client_id='$user_id' AND status='5'") or die(mysql_error())) { 

/* Выборка результатов запроса */ 
while( $count_not = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_count_not) ){ 
$count_not_rows = $count_not['count_not_rows'];
    echo "<h4>Возвратов: <div style='float:right;'><b class='label-orange label-danger'>".$count_not_rows." шт.</b></div></h4>";
} 

/* Освобождаем используемую память */ 

mysqli_free_result($result_count_not); 
} 


/* Посылаем запрос серверу */ 
if ($result_orders = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT SUM(summa) AS OrderTotal FROM orders WHERE client_id='$user_id'") or die(mysql_error())) { 

/* Выборка результатов запроса */ 
while( $row_orders = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_orders) ){ 
$total = $row_orders['OrderTotal'];
$nombre_format = number_format($total, 0, ' ', ' ');
    echo "<h4>Сумма заказов: <div style='float:right;'><b class='label-orange label-primary'>".$nombre_format." грн.</b></div></h4>";
 } 

/* Освобождаем используемую память */ 
mysqli_free_result($result_orders); 
} 

?>

</div>

<div style="padding: 0px 30px 0;" class="col-sm-5" >
<h4>Моя скидка: <div style="float:right;"><b class="label-orange label-success"><?php if($total > 0){echo '8';}else{echo '0';}?> %</b></div></h4>
<?php 

$otckaz_row = $otckaz_rows / 5;
$count_ok = $count_rows - $count_not_rows - $otckaz_row; // Всего заказов - возвратов
$rep_info = 100 / $count_rows; // 100 делим на колличество заказов
$rep_ok = $rep_info * $count_ok; // % за один заказ * колличество успешных заказов
$nombre_rep_format = number_format($rep_ok, 2, '.', ' '); // переводим результат в читаемый вид
if($rep_ok >= 70){ // Проверяем нужен ли залог при заказе
$rep_view = "label-success";
}else
{
$rep_view = "label-danger";
}
?>
<h4>Моя репутация: <div style="float:right;"><b class='label-orange<?php echo " ".$rep_view."'>".$nombre_rep_format."%";?></b></div></h4>
<button type="button" style="font-family: Rubik;font-size: 13px;" class="btn m-t-md btn-default btn-block" onclick="location.href='./settings';"> <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Изменить E-mail</button>
<button type="button" style="font-family: Rubik;font-size: 13px;" class="btn m-t-md btn-default btn-block" onclick="location.href='./settings';"> <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Изменить пароль</button>
<button type="button" style="font-family: Rubik;font-size: 13px;" class="btn m-t-md btn-default btn-block" onclick="location.href='./settings';"> <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Зачем нужна репутация?</button>
<button type="button" style="font-family: Rubik;font-size: 13px;" class="btn m-t-md btn-default btn-block" onclick="location.href='./settings';"> <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Как повысить репутацию?</button>
</div>
</div><br>

<?php 
if($nombre_rep_format < 70){

echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
<strong>Внимание!!!</strong> В связи с тем что у Вас уровень репутации менее 70% отправка Ваших заказов временно будет осуществляться по предоплате <strong>50 грн</strong>.
</div>";
}
?>

<h2>История заказов</h2>

<table cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
  <th>ID заказа</th>
  <th>Дата</th>
  <th>Кол-во</th>
  <th>Сумма</th>
  <th>Скидка</th>
  <th>Статус</th>
  <th>#</th>
 </tr>

 <?php

/* Посылаем запрос серверу */ 
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE client_id='$user_id'")) { 

/* Выборка результатов запроса */ 
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
$total_order = $row['summa'];
$nombre_order_format = number_format($total_order, 0, ' ', ' ');
if($row['status'] == 1){
    $status = "<span class='label label-success'>В обработке</span>";
    }else{
        if($row['status'] == 2){
        $status = "<span class='label label-info'>Собираем</span>";
            }else{
                if($row['status'] == 3){
                $status = "<span class='label label-info'>Доставка</span>";
                    }else{
                        if($row['status'] == 4){
                        $status = "<span class='label label-primary'>Выполнено</span>";
                            }else{
                                if($row['status'] == 5){
                                $status = "<span class='label label-danger'>Возврат</span>";
                                    }else{
                                        if($row['status'] == 6){
                                        $status = "<span style='background:#4682B4;padding:3px;color:#ffffff'><b>Отмена</b></span>";
                                            }else{
                                                $status = "Ошибка";
                                                /*Нужно добавить запись в базу о возможно вторжении + IP и если есть ID пользователя*/
                                                 }
                                         }
                                 }
                         }
                 }
         }
    printf("
    <tr>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s шт</td>
    <td>".$nombre_order_format." грн</td>
    <td>%s грн</td>
    <td>".$status."</td>
    <td>
        <form method='post' action='#'>
        <input type='hidden' name='open_order' value='open_order'>
        <div class='form-actions'>
        <a><button class='button_block' type='submit'><a>Открыть</a></button></a>
        </div>
        </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    ", $row['id'], $row['dt_added'], $row['amount'], $row['discount']);
}

/* Освобождаем используемую память */ 
mysqli_free_result($result); 
}

/* Закрываем соединение */ 
mysqli_close($link); 
  ?>

</table>

        <form class="ajax" method="post" action="./ajax.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="act" value="logout">
        <div class="form-actions">
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Выйти</button>
        </div>
        </form>

        <?php else: ?>

        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=login.php" />
        <div class="error_403"></div>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div> <!-- END of content -->
    <div class="cleaner"></div>
</div> <!-- END of main -->

<?php include ('_files/_footer.php');?>

</div>

 <script src="./js/ajax-form.js"> </script>
 <script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/vendor/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/vendor/underscore.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/modules/catalog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/modules/cart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/modules/compare.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/modules/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: сначала головой, а потом руками

Comment: Использовать современный подход, конструкцию MVC (php framework, yii, laravel, code igniter и т.д.) переписав эту ерунду выше, тогда всё станет намного удобней и красивей для разработки, где будет отдельно логика запросов к базе, отдельно html код и т.д.

Comment: очевидно, отделить логику от html для начала. почитайте про twig или smarty.

Comment: Больше всего мне понравился кусок с вереницей if'ов

Comment: @RifmaMan пролистал просторы интернета, информации много но немножко устаревшей с неработающими примерами. Может ты знаешь место где можно изучить (хотя бы поверхностно) MVC?

Comment: @soulwolf изучение этой модели я советую начать с фреймворка `Code Igniter`, есть [офф сайт](https://codeigniter.com/) на котором можно скачать последнюю 3ю версию и там же скачать/ознакомиться с документацией, [русскоязычный клон](http://codeigniter3.info/) поможет понять его основы, но на него не стоит опираться постоянно, я смогу помочь со всеми вопросами (заинтересуешься, пиши), т.к. сейчас работаю с ним ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать современный подход, конструкцию MVC (php framework, yii, laravel, code igniter и т.д.) переписав эту ерунду выше, тогда всё станет намного удобней и красивей для разработки, где будет отдельно логика запросов к базе, отдельно html код и связка всего взаимодействия.

Изучение этой модели я советую начать с фреймворка Code Igniter, есть [офф сайт](https://codeigniter.com/) на котором можно скачать последнюю 3ю версию и там же скачать/ознакомиться с документацией, [русскоязычный перевод](http://codeigniter3.info/guide/tutorial/index) поможет понять его основы, но на него не стоит опираться постоянно, я смогу помочь со всеми вопросами (заинтересуешься, пиши), т.к. сейчас работаю с ним ;-)

Вот [статья](http://sitear.ru/material/mvc-php) для примера как вообще всё устроено, просто прими это как должное (изучи MVC), прочти и работай как современный php разработчик ;-)

Comment: спасибо, в ближайшее время начну изучение

Comment: @soulwolf, будут вопросы, пиши мне в аську, которую найдешь здесь в инфе об аккаунте ;-)